# How to close a windows opener after hitting the servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I wanna close the pop up child window and reload the parent window after hitting the servlet in java. Is there any example that helps me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript to do this:

1. use ajax to call servlet
2. in the ajax callback, code like this:

   window.close();             //close popup window

   window.opener.location.reload();   //reload parent window

Comment: How can i call a servlet in ajax?

Comment: I tried doing that using javascript. It works in chrome not in mozilla

Comment: How do you try? Post some code!!Edit the question with the code in it!